# Find unused pseudoterminal pair in systemd service?

Tags: debian, systemd, pty

Application for which I'm writing service file expects its `STDIN` to be connected to the `tty`, or in other words to be run on the terminal. `Systemd` has the following settings which do the trick for my application, however here I use statically configured `tty` path, which could potentially already be used by other application or simply do not exist on the system.

```
StandardInput=tty-force
TTYPath=/dev/tty30
```

It would be much nicer if `systemd` (or me for that matter) could figure out unused `pseudoterminal` pair and use that instead.

Comment: What are you expecting to have an open file descriptor for the master side of the pseudo-terminal?

Comment: @JdeBP Hopefully no other process should consume master `pty` of the running service, at present nothing is attached to it. To my best knowledge systemd docs say nothing about the requirement to hang some other process on the master `pty`.

Comment: You are misunderstanding one of the basic ideas of pseudo-terminals.  And systemd doco is the wrong place to be looking for how pseudo-terminals work.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man systemd.exec`. the feature you are looking for is not built into `systemd`.

As an alternative, you can write another small service that finds a free TTY, then writes out a `systemd` unit file with the hardcoded TTY, then calls `systemctl start` on the just-in-time unit file.

Comment: I suspected there's no built-in method in the `systemd`, therefore I also asked whether I could figure out a free `pty`, but I suppose it deserves a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that does not rely on systemd at all, and instead uses the commonly available `script` command. For example:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/script -e -c "/usr/bin/python3 -m http.server" /dev/null
```

will execute `python3` with a pseudo-terminal allocated by `script`. The transcript file is discarded to `/dev/null`.

Older versions of `script` do not appear to handle signals correctly, so a kludge like `KillSignal=SIGKILL` might be needed. (`script` with `util-linux` 2.37.2 works without this.)

From `man script`:

```
-c, --command command
           Run the command rather than an interactive shell. This makes it
           easy for a script to capture the output of a program that behaves
           differently when its stdout is not a tty.
```